# How to persist multidimensional Java arrays using JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I want to convert a class of an application that works in memory into an entity in order to persist it, but it contains a double type field [] []. I searched, but did not find how I can rewrite it to be persistent.

```
public class MyClass{

protected int num;

private double[] tab;

private double a[][];

private double b[][];

....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this for PostgreSQL (one of the very few databases that support SQL arrays), you can try and using custom converters. As shown in this example https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

The algorithm to convert to string format is the following:

```
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(double[][] arr) {
    if (arr == null) {
        return null;
    }
    // verify array
    int len1 = arr.length;
    int len2 = -1;
    for (double[] ar : arr) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(ar);
        if (len2 == -1) {
            // first iteration only, if non-empty
            len2 = ar.length;
        }
        else {
            if (len2 != ar.length) {
                throw new RuntimeException("PostgreSQL multidimensional arrays require same lengths on every level");
            }
        }
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('{');
    for (double[] ar : arr) {
        sb.append('{');
        for (double a : ar) {
            sb.append(a).append(',');
        }
        sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);
        sb.append("},");
    }
    sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
}
```

You should be able to make the algorithm for reading them when you know this part. Just don't rely on `split` or regexes, and you can probably skip the validation.

This does not cover arrays of strings, which require special escaping, and in some cases surrounding in double-quotes. That algorithm is not described properly anywhere, and you'll have to find it in the server's source code. You can find my attempt to implement it [here](https://github.com/mopano/hibernate-array-type/blob/86e4048764b797f7726803a08ab1fcf082d01fbe/src/main/java/com/mopano/hibernate/array/java/GenericArrayTypeDescriptor.java#L124) in my module that allows you to use single-dimensional arrays of many non-primitive types.

If you need it for another type of database that does not support arrays, you can just save it as text using a custom format, or even just simple JSON conversion using Attribute Converters.